# How to make labels placed on QGridLayout more consistent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I am making simple program, that reads some data from database and displays it in a window. I decided to use QGridLayout from PyQt5, but can't go around inconsistency in width of labels placed on that layout.
Below is stripped down version with random texts instead of database data. I would like to stretch some labels to the right ALWAYS but sometimes (depending on text) they're taking only part of space designed for them. What do i do wrong?
Examples:
[image][image]
"Refresh" button changes text to different random and changes layout as well.
Code:

```
import random
import string
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, qApp, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget


class GardenHelperUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Garden Helper')
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.generalLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.bt_refresh = QPushButton('Refresh')
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.status_bar = self.statusBar()
        self.status_bar.showMessage('Ready')
        self.tool_bar()
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.bt_refresh)
        self.display_record()

    def tool_bar(self):
        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('img\exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)
        self.bt_refresh.clicked.connect(self.display_record)

    def display_record(self):
        pl_namex = random_text(15)
        en_namex = random_text(15)
        lat_namex = random_text(15)
        descx = random_text(200)
        seedx = random_text(200)
        watx = random_text(200)
        likesx = random_text(200)
        maintx = random_text(200)
        self.clear_layout(self.generalLayout)
        self.create_label(pl_namex, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
        self.create_label(en_namex, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3)
        self.create_label(lat_namex, 1, 7, 2, 2, 3)
        self.create_label('Description:', 3, 1, 1, 2, 2)
        self.create_label(descx, 3, 3, 2, 9)
        self.create_label('Likes', 5, 1, 1, 2, 2)
        self.create_label(likesx, 5, 3, 2, 9)
        self.create_label('Seeding:', 7, 1, 1, 2, 2)
        self.create_label(seedx, 7, 3, 2, 9)
        self.create_label('Watering:', 9, 1, 1, 2, 2)
        self.create_label(watx, 9, 3, 2, 9)
        self.create_label('Maintenance:', 11, 1, 1, 2, 2)
        self.create_label(maintx, 11, 3, 2, 9)

    def create_label(self, label_text, pos_x: int, pos_y: int, rspan: int = 1, cspan: int = 1,
                     stylex: int = 1,
                     align=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop):
        new_label = QLabel(label_text)
        if stylex == 1:
            new_label.setStyleSheet('font: 11pt Roboto Light; color: black; background-color: #E7ECB1; border-style: '
                                    'solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black')
        elif stylex == 2:
            new_label.setStyleSheet('font: 11pt Roboto Condensed; color: black')
        elif stylex == 3:
            new_label.setStyleSheet('font: 11pt Roboto Light Italic; color: #007E1F; background-color: #E2E2E2; '
                                    'border-style: '
                                    'solid; border-width: 0.5px; border-color: #969890')
        new_label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(new_label, pos_x, pos_y, rspan, cspan, align)

    def clear_layout(self, layout):
        while layout.count() > 0:
            item = layout.takeAt(0)
            if not item:
                continue
            w = item.widget()
            if w:
                w.deleteLater()


def random_text(length):
    text_list = []
    letters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ' ' * 10)
    for i in range(length):
        text_list.append(letters[random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)])
    text_str = ''.join(text_list)
    # print(text_str)
    return text_str


def main():
    garden_helper = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GardenHelperUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(garden_helper.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don’t understand why do all the time to reform

```
new_label = QLabel (label_text)
```

and why do you need the  `clear_layout` method

try it:

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
import random
import string
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, qApp, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget


baseUIClass, baseUIWidget = uic.loadUiType("garden_helper.ui")


class GardenHelperUI(QMainWindow, baseUIClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Garden Helper')
#        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)

        self.bt_refresh = QPushButton('Refresh')
        self.status_bar = self.statusBar()
        self.status_bar.showMessage('Ready')
        self.tool_bar()
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.bt_refresh)

        self._dictLabel = {
            'pl_namex':   random_text(15),
            'en_namex':   random_text(15),
            'lat_namex':  random_text(15),
            'descx':      random_text(200),
            'seedx':      random_text(200),
            'watx':       random_text(200),
            'likesx':     random_text(200),
            'maintx':     random_text(200),
        }

        self.stylex()
        self.display_record()

    def tool_bar(self):
        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('img\exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)
        self.bt_refresh.clicked.connect(self.refresh_record)           # refresh_record

    def stylex(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            #descx, #seedx, #watx, #likesx, #maintx {
                font: 11pt Roboto Light;                
                color: black; 
                background-color: #FFECB1;              
                border-style: solid; 
                border-width: 1px; 
                border-color: black;
            }
            #description, #likes, #seeding, #watering, #maintenance {
                font: 11pt Roboto Condensed; 
                color: black;
            }            
            #pl_namex, #en_namex, #lat_namex {
                font: 11pt Roboto Light Italic; 
                color: #007E1F; 
                background-color: #E2E2E2;
                border-style: solid; 
                border-width: 0.5px; 
                border-color: #969890;
                max-width: 150px;
                min-width: 150px;
                max-height: 30px;
            }             
        ''')

    def display_record(self):
        self.pl_namex.setText(self._dictLabel['pl_namex'])
        self.en_namex.setText(self._dictLabel['en_namex'])
        self.lat_namex.setText(self._dictLabel['lat_namex'])
        self.descx.setText(self._dictLabel['descx'])
        self.seedx.setText(self._dictLabel['seedx'])
        self.watx.setText(self._dictLabel['watx'])
        self.likesx.setText(self._dictLabel['likesx'])
        self.maintx.setText(self._dictLabel['maintx'])

    def refresh_record(self):
        self._dictLabel['pl_namex'] = random_text(15)
        self._dictLabel['en_namex'] = random_text(15)
        self._dictLabel['lat_namex'] = random_text(15)
        self._dictLabel['descx'] = random_text(200)
        self._dictLabel['seedx'] = random_text(200)
        self._dictLabel['watx'] = random_text(200)
        self._dictLabel['likesx'] = random_text(200)
        self._dictLabel['maintx'] = random_text(200)
        self.display_record()


def random_text(length):
    text_list = []
    letters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ' ' * 10)
    for i in range(length):
        text_list.append(letters[random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)])
    text_str = ''.join(text_list)
    return text_str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    garden_helper = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GardenHelperUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(garden_helper.exec_())
```

---

**garden_helper.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>750</width>
    <height>594</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="6">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="waterin">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Watering:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="1" colspan="6">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="maintx">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>4</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="pl_namex">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="5">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lat_namex">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="4">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="likes">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Likes:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="3">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="en_namex">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="1" colspan="6">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="likesx">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>4</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1" colspan="6">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="seedx">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>4</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="description">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeIncrement">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="autoFillBackground">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Description:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="maintenance">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Maintenance:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="6">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="descx">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>4</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="1" colspan="6">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="watx">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>4</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="seeding">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Seeding:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @S. Nick for useful hints. I decided to create UI dynamically because I need sometimes to remove all widgets and replace them with QTextEdits to edit records or add new ones. But yes, fixedSize or fixedWidth does the job. 
Also before I used clear_layout method, then after creating new labels (which had different sizes everytime), the old labels were left and visible underneath.
And because I'm still developing it, design changes all the time and it's easier for me to create widgets dynamically.